# Wrong values calculating FFT with EEG Bands using Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, fft

First of all I have to say I am very new to these matters. I am trying to apply FFT algorithm to some values obtained by EEG bands.
I found the following code but I am unable to make it work correctly.
import numpy as np

```
fs = 200                                
#data = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 1024)  # 2 sec of data b/w 0.0-100.0

data = np.array([(-0.27,-0.09,0.16,0.01,0.67,0.65,-1.59,0.11,-0.36,0.69,0.94,0.43,-0.53,-0.57,0.98,-0.97),(-0.74,-0.56,0.76,0.58,1.79,2.22,-4.96,-0.25,-1.19,1.57,2.95,1.47,-1.00,-1.06,2.97,-3.43),
(-0.89,-1.50,1.76,1.72,2.09,4.04,-7.97,-1.30,-2.09,1.11,4.82,2.57,-0.01,0.05,4.64,-6.44),
(-0.84,-2.78,3.00,2.88,2.00,6.36,-11.46,-2.36,-3.22,-0.01,6.96,3.84,1.85,2.11,6.64,-10.31),
(-0.39,-4.27,4.26,4.57,1.09,8.77,-14.78,-4.09,-4.40,-1.87,9.03,5.12,4.86,5.31,8.76,-14.77)])

print("After data")
# Get real amplitudes of FFT (only in postive frequencies)
fft_vals = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(data))
print("After fft_vales")
print(fft_vals)
# Get frequencies for amplitudes in Hz
fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(data), 1.0/fs)
print("After fft_freq")
print(fft_freq)
# Define EEG bands
eeg_bands = {'Delta': (0, 4),
         'Theta': (4, 8),
         'Alpha': (8, 12),
         'Beta': (12, 30),
         'Gamma': (30, 45)}

# Take the mean of the fft amplitude for each EEG band
eeg_band_fft = dict()
for band in eeg_bands:  
   freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= eeg_bands[band][0]) & 
                   (fft_freq <= eeg_bands[band][1]))[0]
   eeg_band_fft[band] = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])

print(eeg_band_fft)
```

I am getting the following errors when it goes into the `for`.

```
/home/xxxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3372: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
/home/xxxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:170: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

What am I missing or what's wrong?

As I said above, I am very new to this matter so please, try to explain everything as simple as possible.

EDIT 1

This is the result I get:

```
band        val
0  Delta  64.642945
1  Theta        NaN
2  Alpha        NaN
3   Beta        NaN
4  Gamma  25.851368
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo, change this code:

```
# Take the mean of the fft amplitude for each EEG band
eeg_band_fft = dict()
for band in eeg_bands:  
   freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= eeg_bands[band][0]) & 
                   (fft_freq <= eeg_bands[band][1]))[0]
eeg_band_fft[band] = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])

print(eeg_band_fft)
```

to read

```
# Take the mean of the fft amplitude for each EEG band
eeg_band_fft = dict()
for band in eeg_bands:  
   freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= eeg_bands[band][0]) & 
                   (fft_freq <= eeg_bands[band][1]))[0]
   eeg_band_fft[band] = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])

print(eeg_band_fft)
```

Notice the indentation of one line. With that, you should see the output:

```
{'Alpha': nan,
 'Beta': nan,
 'Delta': 2.0749711266314317,
 'Gamma': 6.3502280534780855,
 'Theta': nan}
```

Note, the `nan`'s and the error occurs because for some of the bands `fft_vals[freq_ix]` is empty. You can confirm this by printing the value of `fft_vals[freq_ix]` for each band.

Also note that numpy will only print such an error/warning once, even if you have many occurrences.

Comment: Actually, the indent was correct. It was my issue doing it wrong when writing it here. Let me update it and I will also add the result I currently get.

Comment: @NeoChiri other than the fact that you get different numbers than what I get when I run the same code, I don't see why there is any issue with your code. The only issue may be in your understanding in what you are trying to compute, it appears some of the bands are simply void of data in the data that you supplied.

Comment: Also are you sure you want to use the 1D DFT vs the 2D DFT? Your data seems to be two dimensional, so it stands to reason your spectral analysis should be as well, unless of course, your data is actually one dimensional and you are simply computing the DFT in batches? For the n-dimensional DFT use `numpy.fft.fftn` or `numpy.fft.fft2`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftn.html#numpy.fft.fftn